# What kind of icons are available to depict object specific states

Tags: user-interface, icons

What kind of icons can be used to show an object specific state

- e.g. user who has just been created, user who has been activated so that he can use the portal, user who has been removed from the system
- e.g an object which has just been created and still in the draft stage and an object which has been activated or de-activated and cannot be used

Comment: http://ui.stackexchange.com/ is in beta now and should get you much better answers than SO can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how to reply...to best get an idea, get an icon archive such as Oxygen Icons or Crystal Icons.

- new user: a user icon with a green + in bottom-right corner
- new object: depends on the type of object, a generic icon would be an object icon (maybe a circle) and a green + in the bottom right
- normal object: object a with a green tick sign
- archived object: object a with a gray tick sign

Comment: The icons which you have mentioned above, are they readily available on the web?

Comment: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Oxygen+Icons?content=74184   and    http://www.everaldo.com/crystal/?action=downloads